# Remove everything before br tag Regex

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

How do I remove everything before the first `br` tag in regex Yahoo pipes?

Regex module

```
in [item.description] replace [.+(<br>)] with [mytext]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours:

```
in [item.description] replace [.+(<br>)] with [mytext]
```

Correct:

```
in [item.description] replace [.+?(<br>)] with [mytext]
```

See: [Greedy vs. non-greedy matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy).

Also, the parentheses are superfluous. `.+?<br>` would work as well.

Comment: thanks @tomalak. The reference you gave was useful too. If to replace everything before the 2nd br tag, what will the regex be?

Comment: theoretically, `replace [.+?<br>.+?<br>] with [nothing]`(or a slight variation of that, depending on the input), but regular expressions are not the right tools for working with HTML, so giving a definitive answer is impossible. There can only be answers that work for certain inputs.